# Linq select only when exactly matching found

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table as shown below

```
user | roomNo
--------------
  A  | R1
  B  | R1
  A  | R2
  C  | R2
  A  | R3
  B  | R3
  E  | R3
```

Besides, I have a list of user which numbers are not certain (based on the parameter passed in, but at least there will be 2 users.)

This is the method i get user:
var user = userlist.Split(',');

my question is:
how can i using linq to get the roomNo for the exactly match of number of user and the value of user

Example:

1. There are 2 users (and the users are A and B), system should return roomNo R1
2. There are 3 users (and the users are A,B and E), system should return roomNo R3

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear with your question, including real snippets of code? `var user = userlist.Split(',');` is absolutely meaningless to us, because we don't know what `userlist` is, and don't know the format of the string (presumably CSV, but you never know).

Comment: @Rob I don't think that'll quite do it.  I believe it'll return both sets (where `A and B` and also where `A, B and E`).

Comment: @BrendanGreen Ah yes, you're right

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got a data structure something like this:

```
class Reservation
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string RoomNo { get; set; }
}
```

This would query what you're after:

```
var input = new[] { "A", "B", "E" };

// start with reservations
var room = reservations
    // create a grouping by the room number
    .GroupBy(r => r.RoomNo)
    // filter groupings that contain all `input` elements
    .Where(g => input.All(i => g.Select(rs => rs.User).Contains(i)))
    // filter groupings to those whose reservations only include elements in `input` 
    .Where(g => g.All(r => input.Contains(r.User)))
    // select the grouping key, which is the room number. 
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below you could try:

```
var usersWhoHaveBookedRooms = db.UserRoomInfoTbl.Where(x=> users.contains(x.user)).ToList();

var bookedRooms = (from item in usersWhoHaveBookedRooms 
                   group item by item.roomNo
                   select item).ForEach(x=> new {
                   RoomNumber = x.Key,
                   Users = x.Value //Note: cretea csv of userid from here
                   }).ToList()
```

Code is just to give an idea. It won't compile.